# What is "ext4-rsv-conver" process?

Tags: linux, process, ext4, documentation

Does anyone have documentation on `ext4-rsv-conver`?

```
$ pgrep -a -f ext4-rsv-conver 
153 ext4-rsv-conver
161 ext4-rsv-conver
7451 ext4-rsv-conver
$ dpkg -S ext4-rsv-conver
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *ext4-rsv-conver*
```

I can't find anything about `ext4-rsv-conver` in Google.
My system is Debian 9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These processes are kernel threads, used by [the `ext4` implementation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/ext4/super.c?id=73ba2fb33c492916853dfe63e3b3163da0be661d#n4297) to handle conversion work from writeback, *i.e.* [“completed IOs that need unwritten extents handling and have transaction reserved”](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/ext4/ext4.h?id=73ba2fb33c492916853dfe63e3b3163da0be661d#n1033).

That probably doesn’t explain much, but it does mean they’re nothing to worry about. Basically the kernel ends up with work which needs to be dealt with “out of band”, and uses a work queue with dedicated threads to handle it (instead of blocking the calling process or interrupt).