# Can I get rid of "ext4-rsv-conversion" process?

Tags: linux, ext4, ext3

uname -a gives:
Linux devuan 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1 (2018-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
All filesystems on all disks in this box are `ext3` (~15T worth over six disks)
ps -A gives:

```
...
14684 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sdc1-8
14685 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
14688 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sdc2-8
14689 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
14692 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sdc3-8
14693 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
14696 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sdd1-8
14697 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
14700 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sdd2-8
14701 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
14704 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sdd3-8
14705 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
14708 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sdd4-8
14709 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
14712 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sdf1-8
14713 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
...
```

Googling doesn't find explanation for "ext4-rsv-conver" to exist, especially since all I use are ext3.
Why does this exist here, is it really needed & can I get rid of it?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463210/some-documentation-for-the-ext4-rsv-conver-process

Comment: @Thomas: yea, I saw that but that and the links unfortunately gives me no info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 4.3 of the kernel, Ext3 file systems are handled by the Ext4 driver. That driver uses [workqueues named `ext4-rsv-conversion`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463210/some-documentation-for-the-ext4-rsv-conver-process), one per file system; there is no way to get rid of them.

Comment: thx. I've been holding on to ext3 until 4 is proven safe: has the jury come back yet? I see in the 'Related'-section questions re corruption, less disk-space => rsync-problem, ... Would it be worth it? is a mixed 3 & 4 ok? since ext4-driver is used for 3 does that mean ext3 is doomed?

Comment: Ext4 has been considered stable enough for general use for ten years, and the Ext3 driver was removed three years ago. The on-disk format isn’t going away any time soon; Ext2 is still supported... A mixed setup is perfectly OK.

Comment: These days, ext4 is probably much more stable than ext3, because most systems use ext4.  As others mentioned, the kernel code is the same, but the combination of features is different, which puts ext3-format users into more corner cases that get tested less often.  Also, ext4 is faster in a number of areas (block allocation via extents, fsck due to flexbg, etc.). Some of these features can be enabled by tune2fs, some only at format time.